Liferay - Menu navigation - Breadcrumbs
I am working with liferay 7.4, I have created a navigation menu that contains Submenu, I need to group pages without having links.
I have created an ADT template to show that menu, the problem I have encountered is that I need to incorporate a breadcrumb, but it shows me the page path.
I need to create a breadcrumb ADT template that shows the path of my navigation menu, but when using the options provided by the entries in those types of templates, I can't find a way to link it.
This is my template but it shows the pages, not the custom navigation menu.
<#if entries?has_content>
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <#list entries as entry>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <#if entry?has_next>
      <a class="breadcrumb-link"

        <#if entry.isBrowsable()>
              href="${htmlUtil.escapeAttribute(entry.getURL()!"")}"
            </#if>
      >
        <span class="breadcrumb-text-truncate">
              ${htmlUtil.escape(entry.getTitle())}</span>
      </a>
        <#else>
      <span class="active breadcrumb-text-truncate">${htmlUtil.escape(entry.getTitle())}</span>
        </#if>
      </li>
    </#list>
  </ol>
</#if>


There is a breadcrumb portlet in liferay which is better suited for this I think.
